# How to generate link with youtube-dl for downloading video from YouTube with title?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

With youtube-dl I can get url for video, which opens browser video player. I need download it with title.
This link from internet works:

```
http://r3---sn-8p8v-bg0ed.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-AMwj6zvohEaPL1fiBRIGkayxokFNVhQ4A1VF6u2HWlc5&ipbits=0&mm=31&mn=sn-8p8v-bg0ed&dur=0.000&expire=1498841617&lmt=1460236973006213&ip=152.250.251.21&usequic=no&ms=au&mt=1498819907&mv=m&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cusequic%2Cexpire&pl=24&ei=sS1WWePVKc6_wQT6mZSADQ&itag=43&ratebypass=yes&initcwndbps=1577500&beids=%5B9466591%5D&mime=video%2Fwebm&key=yt6&source=youtube&signature=51394917CC585F4286B1CD59AE11420FA6FA7065.73A2EC80BBF8087CCD4D3222E09AD5882B14CC78&title=SpaceX+lands+rocket+at+sea%2C+makes+history
```

Generated link by youtube-dl opens player:

```
https://r3---sn-a0gxoxu-ig3e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?clen=1561370&key=yt6&requiressl=yes&gir=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&expire=1498847588&lmt=1460152800626042&ei=BEVWWcOIGMOEd9S3p8AC&id=o-ALcFrC_nifKmVOUT4iWaoMn68Uec2eQweC8_glHx3Zws&initcwndbps=2220000&pl=24&dur=178.282&mime=video%2F3gpp&signature=97509B18D589AEC4A600EC18433750F74C598A46.B33CC6F4B98CB9500A634AFA6B8F79C84DBED85B&ms=au&source=youtube&mv=m&mt=1498825879&ipbits=0&mm=31&mn=sn-a0gxoxu-ig3e&itag=17&ip=176.109.219.108&ratebypass=yes
```

I'm trying to find differences inside parameters, and I see "usequic=no, title=", but adding it to my url doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

The second link works for me, it downloads a file named "videoplayback.3gpp". The first downloads a .webm file, with the original title I suppose. I use Chrome.